# Include the stdafx.h from other projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

Inside a visual studio solution, I have two vcproj, one is called `kernellib.vcproj`, another is called `kernerlibtest.vcproj`. As you can guess, the latter is the unit test project for the former.

Now the `kernellib.vcproj` uses precompiled header, and all of the slow WINAPI `includes` are located in `stdafx.h`. This is to make sure that the kernelib can compile fast.

Now, as `kernerlibtest.vcproj` also makes use of the same set of includes, I also want to perform this speed trick to `kernerlibtest.vcproj`, how can I configure my vcproj and solution file to do this?

Comment: You'll be battling C2859 complaining about a mismatch between the .pch and the program database.  I don't think you can make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Enable it here : `Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties-> C/C++ -> PreCompiled Headers` . Change the option "Not Using Precompiled Headers" to "Use /Yu".
( This is how its done in vs2010, hopefully should be same in vs2008 as well )

Comment: but this would refer to the `stdafx.h` in `kernerlibtest.vcproj`, instead of the  `stdafx.h` in `kernerlib.vcproj`, am I right?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question intitally. I think the stdafx.h will be recomputed for your project. I work on a large solution with several projects and the first src build message I see is "ClCompile:  stdafx.cpp"; If you have added the kernellib's .h files to the project , I think they should have been included in the pch.

Comment: Hey, I think you can try multiple /Yc , see : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0atkd6c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx. I think you can give a different name to the kernerlib's precompiled header and then include multiple /Yc to avoid conflict as indicated in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to get this to work. Here's my advice:

- "stdafx.h" (or however you call your precompiled header) should be an internal header for each module.
- You should only include rarely changing headers in stdafx.h, stuff which doesn't change a lot.
- You should treat this strictly as an optimization.
- Only include stdafx.h from you .c/cpp files, not any public headers.
- You should still include the stdlib/winapi headers in your public headers if your headers depend on definitions like HWND. This won't slow down compilation of your library because you're including the precompiled header first.
- In the stdafx.h for kernerlibtest you can even include kernerlib.h (the public header for a dependency). You gain nothing if kernerlib.h is modified frequently.

  - This is useful if you nest a large 3rd party library inside your work tree.